Can't open MS Word document (.docx) as a resource in QT
With the past method, I opened the document directly specifying the exact path
QAxObject *wApp = new QAxObject("Word.Application");
auto docs = wApp->querySubObject("Documents");
auto doc  = docs->querySubObject("Open(QString)", "C:\\pathToFile\\qwe.docx");

if (doc == nullptr) {
    QMessageBox::information(this, "File opening", "File not found");
    wApp->dynamicCall("Quit()");
    delete wApp;
    return;
}

Now I want to make the document files stored in the directory with the .exe file, i.e. resource like this
Example of a file path
I'm trying to open the file this way, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
auto doc = docs->querySubObject("Open(QString)", ":/documents/qwe.docx");

Error:
QAxBase: Error calling IDispatch member Open: Exception thrown by server
             Code       : -2146823114
             Source     : Microsoft Word
 (C:\documents\qwe.docx)
             Help       : wdmain11.chm [24654]
         Connect to the exception(int,QString,QString,QString) signal to catch this exception


The objects embedded in QAxObject know nothing about the Qt resource system, it attempts to interpret it assuming it's a standard path (hence the C:\documents).
Instead of specifying the path to the resource, create a temporary file as a copy of the resource file and work with it from there.
That's the solution I got
// Get path to temporary directory
QTemporaryDir tempDir;
QString tempFilePath = tempDir.path() + "/qwe_copy.docx";

// Copying a file from resources to a temporary directory
QFile::copy(":/documents/qwe.docx", tempFilePath);

QAxObject *wApp = new QAxObject("Word.Application");
auto docs = wApp->querySubObject("Documents");
auto doc = docs->querySubObject("Open(QString)", tempFilePath); // Path to temporary file

Upd: To delete the temporary file use tempDir.remove()
To not receive a notification that a temporary file has not been saved, use doc->dynamicCall("Close(int)", 0) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdsaveoptions)
